# Find the variable change in GDB

Tags: c++, debugging, variables, gdb

I am working in a project where there are more than 100 files of source code. I am debugging it for find an error.

What I need to find is the time when a particular object assigned to a value. ie. This object is `NULL` at first, but some other file changes its value, which I don't know.

Are there any method to find when this variable changes its value ?

What I tried upto now is to put a *breakpoint* on the function where the variable is initilized. I also added a *watchpoint*. But it does not show any point where the value is changing.

Comment: Watchpoint should detect change of value. What is the code (declaration of that variable). How did you add a watchpoint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But it does not show any point where the value is changing.

There are two possible explanations:

1. You've set the watchpoint incorrectly, or
2. The value changes while the process is in kernel mode (GDB watchpoints are not effective for detecting such change).

Example:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int global_a;
int global_b;

int foo()
{
  global_a = 42;
  read(0, &global_b, 1);

  return global_a + global_b;
}

int main()
{
  return foo();
}

gcc -g -Wall t.c

gdb -q ./a.out
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x400563: file t.c, line 16.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at t.c:16
16    return foo();
(gdb) watch global_a
Hardware watchpoint 2: global_a
(gdb) watch global_b
Hardware watchpoint 3: global_b
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 2: global_a

Old value = 0
New value = 42
```

This is a modification of `global_a` in user-space (via direct assignment), and it triggers watchpoint 2 as expected

```
foo () at t.c:9
9     read(0, &global_b, 1);
(gdb) c
Continuing.
                    # Press Enter here
```

This read `0xA == 10` into `global_b`.

```
[Inferior 1 (process 126196) exited with code 064]
```

Note that the exit code is `064 == 52 == 42+10`, but the watchpoint 3 did *not* fire.

> any method to find when this variable changes its value

If you are sure that your "normal" watchpoints are working (e.g. by running above test yourself) and suspect that the variable is being changed via a system call, you can:

1. Print the address of the variable and
2. Run your program under `strace` and look for system calls that could change the value at variable's address.

Using the same example:

```
(gdb) p &global_b
$1 = (int *) 0x601044 <global_b>

strace -e raw=all ./a.out < /dev/zero

execve(0x7ffe1853e530, 0x7ffe1853f920, 0x7ffe1853f930) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x2253000
access(0x7fa66eee48c3, 0)               = -1 (errno 2)
mmap(0, 0x2000, 0x3, 0x22, 0xffffffff, 0) = 0x7fa66f0e8000
...
munmap(0x7f57ece26000, 0x203a2)         = 0
read(0, 0x601044, 0x1)                  = 0x1  ### &global_b is "covered" by the buffer being read into
exit_group(42)                          = ?
+++ exited with 42 +++
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Seems like my variable's value changes while the process is in kernel mode. Thanks again.

Comment: I was not aware such "simple" scenarios are not caught by regular watchpoints in gdb. But once you think about it it is logical, kernel can't allow itself to be interrupted in such a "random" manner. This should really be explained in gdb docs. There is a way around it, though, if you are a bit patient: disable hardware watchpoints (command is set can-use-hw-watchpoints 0). This slows down execution (single step, check, single step, check...) but it catches the change of global_b in your example.